# Lots of first chance Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinderExceptions thrown when dealing with dynamics

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

I've got a standard 'dynamic dictionary' type class in C# -

```
class Bucket : DynamicObject
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, object> m_dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        m_dict[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return m_dict.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }
}
```

Now I call it, as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic d = new Bucket();
    d.Name = "Orion"; // 2 RuntimeBinderExceptions
    Console.WriteLine(d.Name); // 2 RuntimeBinderExceptions
}
```

The app does what you'd expect it to, but the debug output looks like this:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
'ScratchConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
```

*Any* attempt to access a dynamic member seems to output a `RuntimeBinderException` to the debug logs. While I'm aware that first-chance exceptions are not a problem in and of themselves, this does cause some problems for me:

1. I often have the debugger set to "break on exceptions", as I'm writing WPF apps, and otherwise all exceptions end up getting converted to a `DispatcherUnhandledException`, and all the actual information you want is lost. WPF sucks like that.
2. As soon as I hit any code that's using `dynamic`, the debug output log becomes fairly useless. All the useful trace lines that I care about get hidden amongst all the useless `RuntimeBinderException`s

Is there any way I can turn this off, or is the `RuntimeBinder` unfortunately just built like that?

Thanks, Orion

Comment: This occurs when just using the MVC 3 ViewBag under normal working circumstances. It's annoying and disconcerting since exceptions are expensive.

Comment: I'm new to .net world, I'm developing webapp for travel agency using travelport api. API is SOAP based with .wsdl & .xsd files. I created proxy classes using vs015 inbuilt tool. When I use those proxy classes, all flow is fine and the api gives response, but in vs015 'Output window' I get, "Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll", what is reason behind this exception & is this normal vs015 behavior. Thank you all. Although this is not a place to post this type of comment, I thought, I could approach you guys for help from here.SORRY.

Comment: @codemilan You have the same question that I did 7 years ago in 2010... scroll down and look at the two answers, basically these Exceptions are normal behaviour shown when using something built using the `dynamic` keyword in C#... It seems like a poor design decision on part of the C# people at microsoft, but that's the way it is

Comment: Thank you, alot @OrionEdwards

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Whenever a property on a dynamic object is resolved, the runtime tries to find a property that is defined at compile time. From DynamicObject doco:

> You can also add your own members to
>   classes derived from the DynamicObject
>   class. If your class defines
>   properties and also overrides the
>   TrySetMember method, the dynamic
>   language runtime (DLR) first uses the
>   language binder to look for a static
>   definition of a property in the class.
>   If there is no such property, the DLR
>   calls the TrySetMember method.

`RuntimeBinderException` is thrown whenever the runtime cannot find a statically defined property(i.e. what would be a compiler error in 100% statically typed world). From [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception.aspx)

> ...RuntimeBinderException represents a
>   failure to bind in the sense of a
>   usual compiler error...

It is interesting that if you use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), you only get one exception when trying to use the property:

```
dynamic bucket = new ExpandoObject();
bucket.SomeValue = 45;
int value = bucket.SomeValue; //<-- Exception here
```

Perhaps `ExpandoObject` could be an alternative? If it's not suitable you'll need to look into implementing [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx), which is how `ExpandoObject` does dynamic dispatch. However, it is not very well documented and MSDN refers you to the DLR CodePlex for more info.

Answer (score 26):

This was bothering me, too.  I added the exception to the exceptions list so that I could deselect it.  Just follow these steps:

- From the Debug menu, select Exceptions.
- Click the "Add..." button on the bottom right.
- Choose "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" from the Type dropdown.
- Type "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" as the name.
- Click OK.
- The exception type will now appear on the list.  Just deselect it.

I wish this setting could be saved across solutions, but I don't think it can, so you'll have to reapply this setting on every solution.

Comment: For me, this doesn't actually turn off the debug log showing the exception. It does let me cause the debugger to break on these exceptions, but that's not what I want. I want them to stop spewing.

Comment: I still not get it. did you mean we just need to ignore it when we see it output this exception in visual studio? Is that normal??

Comment: I needed to turn off breaking on this exception, and this helped. Thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015: 
Debug menu -> Windows -> Exception settings (Ctrl+Alt+E)