# RuntimeBinderException when using dynamic object make debugging "impossible"

Tags: c#, dynamic, windows-phone-8

I get a `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` everytime i try to get a property from a dynamic object. I ve read several posts about this issue but i can't get rid of these exceptions! I tried a lot of things to get rid of them i.e. [Lots of first chance Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinderExceptions thrown when dealing with dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin) but it won't work. I get an overlow in my debug output and the point that makes it really bad is that the start of my App is slowed down dramatically. It's impossible to test in debug if every start needs about 2min becouse of those exceptions. Any help would be nice :)

Comment: I can't edit my question.. so here comes the forgotten beginning: "Hi guys,\r\n" ;)