# Visual Studio 2013 - Debugging MVC code with ViewBag properties deathly slow and unusable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying out the latest Visual Studio, but debugging the most elementary MVC application with ViewBag dynamic variables gives me a lot of headache.

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 under 32-bit Windows 8 operating system with clean install and every available update applied.

I created new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.5 - New Solution) with folders and core references for MVC after which I added sample Home controller with some element code:

```
dynamic d1 = 1;
dynamic d2 = 2;

ViewData["Vd1"] = 1;
ViewData["Vd2"] = 2;

ViewBag.Vb1 = 1;
ViewBag.Vb2 = 2;
```

Hitting breakpoint at the first line and stepping to the second until the ViewBag property worked fine (instantly) - then, in the Output window I got:

> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll

...and stepping to the second line (ViewBag.Vb2...) took couple of seconds. I tested different dynamic variables to make sure the problems are with ViewBag properties.

***What causes the exception and so slow debugging under IIS Express?*** Extensive use of ViewBag properties makes debugging a nightmare!

Calling again the script under Debug don't cause the exceptions, and debug works fine because the Debugging Symbols are all loaded (guessing).

I tried lots of different suggestions available at Stack Overflow and else over the net, but non of it works!

Comment: The delay is more likely caused by that exception, and a few seconds (once) doesn't sound like a show stopper.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't at the first sight, but if I have 10 dynamic ViewBag properties (for example) and for one (exception) I have to wait around 5 seconds - than that's 50 seconds total for only one controller and one action!
If I terminate debug session, change some code and run it again, i will have to wait another 50 seconds to see the results... So, this is very significant issue, which I haven't seen on x64 Windows 8 under VS 2012. :|

Comment: No, not 8.1 - regular Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same problem. MVC4/5, IIS Express, Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013.  I did not get this issue under Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2012.  Anyone any ideas?

Comment: The answer is [in this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin/6214985#6214985

Comment: The answer is [in this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin/6214985#6214985

Answer (score 1):

One of the overlooked and never reported issues on increasing debug speed for visual studio 2013 ASP .NET apps (MVC and webforms) is to disable browser link.  This is a new feature in VS 2013 which causes a huge amount of overhead and causes pages to load extremely slowly (5-10 seconds in most of my cases).  Disabling it brings it back to Visual Studio 2012 speeds.

See here for how to disable it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to choose another browser other than Internet Explorer.  IF I used Chrome or Firefox, debugging is lightning fast.  Turning off browser link did not help for Internet Explorer for me.

Here is a link on how to change to another browser when debugging.

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#browser-refresh