# JObject to dynamic not working in Newtonsoft.Json 9.0

Tags: c#, json, json.net

There are many answers here which suggest the following ways to use `JObject` as `dynamic`.

`dynamic dynObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);`
OR
`dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);`

My `jsonString` is simple: `{"id":"123","name":"abc"}`.

It does not seem to work in Newtonsoft.Json 9.0. When I try any of these, I still get an object with the Type  `object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}`.

And when I try to access a property by doing `dynObj.id` I get an exception `error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`.

Comment: Show your `jsonString`

Comment: just added the jsonString

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - I just tried this and it appears to work as expected (v9.0.1)?

Comment: I think I will try to create an example outside of my project.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/aXmSUv.

Comment: @dbc thanks for the fiddle. I believe, its something related to my project only then. Trying to use it in .net core 1.1. Thanks for the help guys. I will close this question for now and re-open with my findings. Don't want to waste time of other people.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably seeing the first chance exception being thrown in the debugger when the DLR first tries to bind to a property on the object. This exception can be safely ignored and if you continue running the code it should work fine.

see: [Lots of first chance Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinderExceptions thrown when dealing with dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin)