# Getting Exception in new ASP.NET MVC App Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an exception (System.Web.HTTPException) in a fresh ASP.NET application. Steps to reproduce:
Visual Studio 2017
.NET Framework 4.6.2

1. Create new project of type ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)
2. Select MVC as the project template
3. System.Web.HttpException in BundleConfig.cs, line 11

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
   ```
4. Click Continue
5. 4 additional exceptions of type:

   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Any ideas why a fresh project would throw exceptions like this?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: No. The only thing that comes to mind is a bad Installation or that your IDE was unable to load the jquery Bundle. Also It doesn't happen on my Mashine :)

Comment: @Brezelmann Thanks. I will check to see if VS 2017 is installed correctly or not. It does look like the jQuery bundel was there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these steps

```
From the Debug menu, select Exceptions.
Click the "Add..." button on the bottom right.
Choose "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" from the Type dropdown.
Type "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" as the name.
Click OK.
The exception type will now appear on the list. Just deselect it.
```

More reference [Lots of first chance Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinderExceptions thrown when dealing with dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954531/lots-of-first-chance-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinderexceptions-thrown-when-dealin)

Comment: thank you very much! As it turns out there is some kind of problem wirh VS 2017 and I just did not have to to completely uninstall the reinstall. I switch back to VS 2015. Works mu better now.